# What is the full undead ability mentioned in savage pathfinder?

Tags: savage-worlds

The sorcerer undead bloodline mentiones a full undead ability but I don't find it anywhere.
What does it entail?

Comment: Can you please clarify: your question mentions pathfinder, your tags have savage worlds, which is a different system?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Since 2020 there exists pathfinder for savage worlds adventure edition. And I'm talking abouit THAT savage world edition.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin It does exist. [https://peginc.com/savage-settings/savage-pathfinder/ ]

Comment: @ValhallaGH and Thomas E, yes, I was not aware of it, learn something new every day. Thanks for the explanations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is a Monster Ability.

It is describe around page 244 of *Pathfinder for Savage Worlds*.

> Add +2 to Toughness and Spirit rolls to recover from being Shaken, ignore additional damage from Called Shots, ignore 1 point of Wound penalties, don’t breathe or eat and are immune to disease and poison, don’t Bleed Out, ignore penalties for Illumination up to 10", and can only be healed with magical healing.

It is identical to the Undead monster ability in the core *Savage Worlds* Adventure Edition rules.